# Is it possible to grab the direct flv link from youtube embed code via php?

Tags: php, youtube

I have a custom flash player which requires a flv file url to work. So if someone posts a youtube video embed code, will it be possible to find the direct flv link from that? if there isn't, what would be my best alternative to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a thin web client or cURL through PHP to load up the embed URL.

From the returned page grab the string containing "**videoplayback**" - this will be the direct link to the FLV file, with all the params appended.